# Yii validation except on save, real?

Tags: php, validation, yii, except

i have ajax form submit and some validation rules:

```
array('go1, go2', 'type', 'type' => 'time', 'timeFormat' => 'hh:mm', 'except'=>'save'),
array('go1, go2', 'type', 'type' => 'datetime', 'datetimeFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'on'=>'save'),
```

My Controller:

```
if($model->save())
                        {
                            echo CJSON::encode(array(
                                  'status'=>'success'
                             ));
                            Yii::app()->end();
                        } else {
                            $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);
                            if($error!='[]')
                                echo $error;
                            Yii::app()->end();
                        }
```

The problem is, "except" is not ignoring save scenario as expected, as i modify $_POST data it doesn't go through it. Data is saving **without** this rule, but, not validate in  $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);

Anyone know how to make it work? Or maybe there is some rule such as 'on'=>'validation'?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I have achieved my task in another way, $model->save(false), so i validate only once with Yii - CActiveFrom::validation, but before $model-save() now. Then if all is ok, i check another conditions in controller, and if something wrong i return JSON with error.

**But the main question is still on, 2nd rule work only on $model->save(), why then except => save, is not working only in CActiveForm Validation, but in $Model->save too?**

Answer (score 3):

You probably do not use the scenario "save".

The default scenario is "insert" for new records or "update" for existing records.

So the line should be:

```
array('go1, go2',
    'type',
    'type' => 'time',
    'timeFormat' => 'hh:mm',
    'except'=>'insert, update'
),
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work, in this way CActiveForm::validate($model); ignored too... :(

Comment: The documentation says "except" should be an array. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, if i use this rule, even in array, go1 and go2 don't check in CActiveForm::validate($model), but i need that it don't check in model->save(), and check in validate($model)...

Comment: Please provide more info on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. The validation rules doesn't make much sense to me since you are validating different types on the same fields.

Comment: I get time from user in 12:00 format, this is how it takes CActiveForm::validate, later i added date to this, and it's looks like
2014-01-01 12:00:00, and this i check in $model->save. 
So the point is: i'm validate form in ajax, which receive answer from controller method at top..and i need to validate if user enter time in 12:00 format, when i save i check if time changed to datetime format, but rules affect $model-save() too, when except must cut this rule from $model->save().

Comment: It doesn't work that way since a scenario is usually not changed and only set during/after creation. If all you want to do is add a date to the attribute, I would do it in beforeSave(), this is triggered right before saving but after validation. So if this date is not a user input you can generate it and prepend it but be aware that it would not be validated anymore.
Another approach would be you create the model with scenario "validation" (with according validation rules) and change it before saving to another scenario (with other rules). That should work but its not best practice.